# Minimal Hall effect sensor circuit to keep something off after certain RPM achieved

Tags: transistors, sensor, electromagnetism, hall-effect

I have a somewhat limited understanding of electronics and circuits. I'm trying to build a circuit that will keep a transistor in an off state after a given threshold of RPM is achieved using a [A3144E](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.allegromicro.com%2F~%2Fmedia%2FFiles%2FDatasheets%2FA3141-2-3-4-Datasheet.ashx&ei=VvM1VNOgOc2dyAS6uoHABQ&usg=AFQjCNEOdzCEoz2KfzfuhXorAUsx0yxKKg&bvm=bv.76943099,d.aWw&cad=rja) Hall effect sensor.

For example, anything let's say that is below 500 RPM, I would like the transistor to be in an on state, and anything above 500 RPM, the transistor should be in an off state.

How could this be achieved using minimal and common parts without the use of a microcontroller, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an [LM2917](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2907-n.pdf) (or 2907) and a few support components.  Have a look at page 9 of the PDF.  The transistor state is inverted from your requirements, but that's easy to fix with another transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnb8c8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Without actually building and testing it myself, and given that it's 20 years since the only time I've used an LM2917, I'm not going to promise you that this circuit will work - but based on the datasheet it should.  It should cover from about 220rpm to 900rpm; changing the upper and lower revs is just a matter of changing the resistors.

The rpm is set by C1 and (R1+R2).  R2 is adjustable, allowing you to set a resistance of between 33K and 133K.

The relationship between frequency, resistance and capacitance is: F = 1 / 2RC

F is rpm / 60, so:

- rpm / 60 = 1 / 2RC
- rpm = 30 / RC
- Using a 1uF capacitor (as I did in the schematic):
- rpm = 30,000,000 / R

So for a 33K resistor, rpm = 909 and for a 133K resistor, rpm = 226.  Smaller resistor values give higher rpm's.

The normal behaviour is that the (internal) transistor switches on when the frequency is above the set point.  Q2 (and R5) flip that behaviour - Q2 switches off when the frequency is above the setpoint.

Comment: I'm a bit lost what else I would need. I'm trying to figure out what components I would need to make the RPM (frequency input to LM2917) adjustable for testing purposes. Could you do a rough schematic?

Comment: @troop231 Not clear... do you mean that you want to be able to adjust the threshold, to higher or lower than 500rpm?

Comment: Yes, just for testing, and also: Would it be a combination of figures 19 and 20 in the linked PDF to build what I need, except for the transistor change you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: Just figure 20.  Figure 19 is for a voltage output, which is not what you want.

Comment: There appears to be a problem with using the LM2917 for what I want. It says the minimum voltage should be around 12 volts, and my system will use a 12V battery. Doesn't leave much room for error when the battery discharges slightly. Are there other chips that work on a lower voltage that do something similar?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the 12V minimum from.  I can't find a minimum specified anywhere, but I suspect that it's 5V.  The absolute maximum is specified as 28V, and one of the application circuits show a Vcc as low as 5V.

Comment: markt, You're right. I was looking at mouser's website and that's what they had listed unfortunately. In your schematic, does Q2 solve for keeping the device on until the threshold is exceeded, and which exact R values in the schematic need changed if I wish to experiment? Hoping the Capacitor values don't need changed too. Thank you again!

Comment: Is it okay if I substitute the 2N3904 in your schematic for a P2N2222A transistor? It will be more suitable for my needs. Also, will I need to change any other part of the circuit if I do this? Thank you again!

Comment: The 2N3904 is just the default NPN transistor in the circuit editor this site uses; you can use whatever general-purpose NPN transistor you want.  Whatever transistor you use for Q2, if you find that it doesn't switch strongly or reliably enough, use a smaller value for R5.

Comment: Quick update: the circuit didn't work. The transistor Q2 always stays on for some reason. I used a 223K ohm resistor for R1 (no R2) to set a small threshold and placed a magnet on my drill and spun it, the indicator light I was turning on with Q2 did not go off as it's supposed to with this circuit. What could be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I also tried the opposite, removing Q2 and turning the light on with the chip's internal transistor, and it didn't work either.

Comment: @troop231 I missed that the A3144 has an open-collector output.  Add a pullup resistor - try 10K to start with - to its output.  I've added it in the circuit diagram.

Comment: The pull-up still didn't help. I'm also trying this with this sensor: http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/M12-hall-effect-magnetic-sensor-switch_1341620076.html but there's no datasheet for it. It's an NPN hall effect sensor as well and confirmed working with the RPM gauge it came with. Would love to get this working. Thank you again!

Comment: At this point its worth verifying that the sensor is actually outputting anything, i.e. that it's sensitive enough to detect the magnet.  If you put a multimeter on the output of the A3144 and move the magnet close and away, does the sensor output change?

Comment: I felt the Q2 transistor and it was very hot powering a small 12V incandescent light, I removed the resistor from Q2's base and the light was still on, which tells me Q2 burnt itself in the on state? Regardless, I have some beefier transistors coming (TIP31C).

Comment: @troop231 Transistors get warm/hot, its one of the things they do.  I doubt 1.2mA (12V/10k) into the base of Q2 would be able to burn it out.  You may have wired something incorrectly.

Comment: I was thinking that the load was too much for the transistor to handle (12v light bulb) and burnt out, because when I removed the resistor to its base, the transistor was still on for some reason. Also, should I be using the LM2907 because it doesn't have a zener diode? Or would that not effect anything. I have the LM2917 right now which has the built in zener.

Comment: @troop231 The zener diode in the 2917 just stabilizes the circuit for changes in voltage, so as your battery flattens and its voltage drops the circuit behaviour doesn't change. Highly unlikely that's the problem.  I think you need to break the circuit into chunks and test each chunk.  Start with the hall effect sensor as I suggested earlier - if you can't get that to work then the rest of it won't matter much!

Comment: @troop231 I would suggest taking a voltage output from the f2c chip, then using a comparator (op-amp) to compare that voltage to one from the wiper of a pot as a voltage divider. The comparator can then trigger whatever you want - maybe a latch circuit (flip-flop) so when it triggers it stays on till reset? Then use that to drive a MOSFET as your switching device.

Comment: @markt How would I go about using my multimeter to see if my sensor(s) are working? I don't have an o-scope.

Comment: @troop231 Separate the hall-effect from the rest of the circuit (no wire from its output to the 2907's input, but leave the pullup in place), put the multimeter on voltage measurement across the output, and move your magnet close to and away from the sensor.  If the voltage varies, then the sensor is working.  If not, you could try a stronger magnet.

Comment: @markt I just confirmed the a3144 works by turning on an LED with it by moving a magnet in front of it and away from it respectively.

Comment: @troop231 OK, that's some good news.  The problem must be somewhere in the 2907 circuit.  I know the chip can work, I've used one myself successfully years ago, but I don't know that I can help troubleshoot it much more without the circuit in front of me and a scope and signal generator.

Comment: @markt If i took a picture of the circuit/breadboard would that help?

Comment: @troop231 not really, I still can't probe it with a scope.  Maybe reframe the question, explaining where you're at, and see if anyone else has any input.  "What's wrong with this 2907 circuit?" might get something useful back.